# Can we restrict the number of connections to a database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, max-connections

I have a database on SQL Server. My web application contacts this database. Is there a way in which I can restrict the number of connections to this database through some settings on the SQL Server?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like we can do it :

To configure the user connections option

- In Object Explorer, right-click a server and click Properties.
- Click the Connections node.
- Under Connections, in the Max number of    concurrent connections
  box, type or select a value from 0 through    32767 to set the
  maximum number of users that are allowed to connect    simultaneously
  to the instance of SQL Server.
- Restart SQL Server.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187030.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know such setting on the server level, but you can write the server-level trigger on connect action which will check the connections' count to the needed DB (bazed on DMVs) an, in case of over limit,  will restrict the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to restrict number of *concurrent* connections then Resource Governor comes in handy. Can even tailor it to specific logins only.